# Is there Wi-Fi and electric socket in long-distance buses in Germany?

Tags: germany, buses, power, wifi

Traveling with Polish bus operator PolskiBus I got used to electric socket and free Wi-Fi on board. I could just charge my smartphone and browse internet or read books.

How does it look like in long-distance buses, such as FlexiBus or BerlinLinienBus, (both internal and foreign connections), in Germany? Is there the possibility to charge your smartphone/notebook? Is there Wi-Fi on board?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- [FlexiBus](https://www.flixbus.de/service) and [Meinferinbus](http://meinfernbus.de/uber-uns/produkt.html) offer Free Wi-Fi, but no electric socket.
- As far as I know berlinlinienbus doesn't offer Wi-Fi nor electric socket.
- Eurolines offers Wi-Fi and electric socket in the [Eurolines Business class buses](http://www.eurolines.de/Eurolines-Business-Class.1393.0.html?&L=1)

Comment: Oh, PolskiBus operator was advertising they are offering a new standard of services, and I see it wasn't only a marketing. In the era of smartphones electric socket is very useful on the long ride. It seems I should consider buying e-book reader...

Answer (score 4):

[ADAC Postbus](https://www.adac-postbus.de/) offer both electric socket and wifi, they advertise with it.